# to receive either a deque or vector as a common parameter in a c++ function

Tags: c++, vector, stl, queue, deque

How to write a print function that receives either a deque or a vector and print the content into the console?

```
void print(generalparameter for deque and vector){
   // print the content of the received deque/ vector.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template function:

```
template<typename T>
void print(const T& container){
   for(auto item : container) {
       std::cout << item << ' ';
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a generic function template:

```
template <typename Container>
void print(Container const& c) {
    for (auto const& elem : c) {
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**P.S.** If you really want to restrict it to *only* `vector` or `deque` you may use something like `static_assert` inside the function's body, but I'm not sure that restriction would really make sense.